# Как сделать блок плавно выезжающим и через 5 сек плавно уезжало

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

Как сделать плавный блок

```
if (json['success']) {
$('#content').before('<div class="alert success__add">' + json['success'] + ' <button type="button" class="icon-close close" data-dismiss="alert"></button></div>');}
```

по клику на кнопку Купить, появится блок информации, этот блок появится сразу

хочется плавный выезжало и плавно уезжало

к классу success__add задан position: fixed; left: 0;bottom: 0;width: 100% ...

нашел такой вариант реализации, почему-то не получается у меня
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033895/how-do-i-wait-for-the-slidetoggle-to-complete-before-executing-code

Comment: Блок уведомления будет выезжать снизу, слева, правильно понимаю?

Comment: хотелось, чтоб выезжало снизу и через 5 сек обратно

Comment: Тогда такой вопрос. Почему вы вставляете уведомление перед #content, если уведомление снизу в углу?

Comment: чтоб вывести этот блок, по всему сайта #content присутствует, поэтом id добавляется уведомление.. в самому блоку уведомление задан position fixed

Comment: У вас доступ к html имеется?

Comment: в принципе нашел простой способ реализации http://joxi.ru/LmGM6QBtZZWaJA